# Change of density during iterations in NSGA-II

Tags: genetic-algorithm, probability-density

I am working with NSGA II and I am wondering, how the density of the population changes while the algorithm is running. Suppose you initialize your population according to a uniform distribution. Your population is changed after each iteration. How does this afflict the density of the  population? E.g. If the sample size is huge will the population after n steps still be roughly uniform distributed? Does anybody know an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Candidate solutions will close after a while. It's normal. Uniform distributon necessary just for first population. If you hesitate to get stuck on a local optimum, you can raise mutation operator probability. Mutation operator provides to jump another area.